# macros in clojurescript - does not expand properly

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lisp-macros

I have created a macro in clojure

```
(ns macro-question.map)

(defmacro lookup [key] (list get (apply hash-map (range 1 5)) key))
```

in the clojure repl it works as expected

```
$ clj
Clojure 1.9.0
user=> (require 'macro-question.map)
nil
user=> (macro-question.map/lookup 1)
2
```

So I create a clojurescript module like this to try to use it:

```
(ns macro-question.core (:require-macros [macro-question.map]))

(defn lookup1 [] (macro-question.map/lookup 1))
```

and when I try that in the repl, I get this

```
$ clj -m cljs.main  --repl-env node
ClojureScript 1.10.520
cljs.user=> (require 'macro-question.core)
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at cljs.compiler/fn (compiler.cljc:304).
failed compiling constant: clojure.core$get@3df1a1ac; clojure.core$get is not a valid ClojureScript constant.
```

meanwhile back in clojure, there is a clue why this might be

```
user=> (macroexpand '(macro-question.map/lookup 1))
(#object[clojure.core$get 0x101639ae "clojure.core$get@101639ae"] {1 2, 3 4} 1)
```

I can create macros that start with `'(` instead of `(list`.  However, I want the map to be expanded at build time.

What is going on?  And what do I have to do to get something like the following:

```
user=> (macroexpand '(macro-question.map/lookup 1))
(get {1 2, 3 4} 1)
```

or what should I be doing to use this macro in clojurescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(list get (apply hash-map (range 1 5)) key)`

Creates a list where the first position is the function object that the var `get` refers to. What you actually want to return is a list with the fully qualified *symbol* for `get` as the first position. Change your macro definition to

```
(defmacro lookup [key] 
  `(get ~(apply hash-map (range 1 5)) ~key))
```

```
(macroexpand '(lookup 1))
=> (clojure.core/get {1 2, 3 4} 1)
```

The reference guide for the reader is helpful here https://clojure.org/reference/reader

Answer (score 1):

You can just put `'get`!!

```
(ns macro-question.map)

(defmacro lookup [key] (list 'get (apply hash-map (range 1 5)) key))
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58985564 is a better answer about why it happens, and a much better way to do it.  This just shows a simple solution that only solves the immediate issue, that I realised right after I had asked the question)

Comment: If you just put `get`, then if the consumer of your macro has redefined `get` in their namespace or lexical scope to mean something else, you'll get that definition instead. If you use syntax-quote as I did, then you're sure that you will be referring to `clojure.core/get`, the `get` that was available in the namespace that defined the macro. Try doing `(let [get nil] (lookup 1))` with your definition

Comment: yeah - updated my answer to reflect that more clearly